# newbie Django select menu 'function' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, object, menu, pydev

when i acess to my url i only get: `<django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x026D1CD0>`
i want the number Choicefield

i have the folowing `models.py` in my app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Zonas(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class ZonasForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Zonas
```

I guess the problem is in my `views.py`:

```
from django    import forms
from testApp.models import Zonas
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def menuForm (request):
    z = list (Zonas.objects.all())
    numbers = forms.ChoiceField(z)
    return render_to_response('hello.html', {'numbers':numbers})
```

menuForm is used on my `urls.py` as:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from testApp.views import menuForm
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^hello/$', menuForm ),
)
```

my `html` page, is as simple as it can be:

```
<html>
<body>

{{numbers}}

</body>
</html>
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Btw, you can use `ModelChoiceField(queryset=Zonas.objects.all())`. Please, show the contents of your html template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url for the page is not correct, change it to

```
url(r'^hello/$', menuForm),
```

As mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.patterns),  it is of the form

> (regular expression, Python callback function [, optional_dictionary [, optional_name]])

Also, change definition of the view function as

```
def menuForm (request):
....
```

Comment: tried it before, that way i get this error: `menuForm() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: @ClaudioA, check ans to update view function, what is `self` parameter that you have defined in the function? Is it part of some class?

Comment: uptaded, i guess is working now, i am just not getting the menu choicefield on my html. instead i get --> `` `<django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x026D1CD0>`

Comment: should i put it as a new question?

Comment: @ClaudioA, I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Doing `numbers = forms.ChoiceField(z)` in view is not usual way. Please readup docs on how to use django forms/model forms.

Comment: I am trying to make a select menu with the options stored in z, and display it on the html page.